# how to migrate "Marshal" methods from C# to Go

Tags: c#, go

i am currently trying to port some piece of code from `C#` to `go` where dll's are involved (not sure if this makes any difference).

the actual "code" is not the problem but i run into some "feature" problems

i have the following line:

```
Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WINMSG)));
```

i know that i can transform

`Marshal.SizeOf` => `unsafe.Sizeof` also typeof is not a problem

but how can i implement the `AllocHGlobal`?

or is this not even needed - just create the instance of a struct and assign a pointer to it?

why do i need this:
there is need for communicating directly with dll's and i have to communicate/exchange data with them.

fully working code is available which needs to be turned into `go`

Done - but untested yet:

```
Marshal.AllocHGlobal
Marshal.FreeHGlobal
```

implementation of the stuff already done

```
import (
    ...
    "github.com/kbinani/win"
    ...
)
type IntPtr int16
type UIntPtr uint64
const uint64 HIWORDMASK = 0xffffffffffff0000

// AllocHGlobal like Marshal.AllocHGlobal from c#
func MarshalAllocHGlobal(numBytes int) (tw.IntPtr, error) {
    pNewMem := win.LocalAlloc( /*LMEM_FIXED*/ 0x0000, numBytes)
    if pNewMem == 0 /*IntPtr.Zero*/ {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("OutOfMemoryException")
    }
    return pNewMem
}

func MarshalFreeHGlobal(hglobal IntPtr) error {
    if IsNotWin32Atom(hglobal) {
        if  0 /*IntPtr.Zero*/ != win.LocalFree(hglobal) {
            return fmt.Errorf("failed to FreeHGlobal")
        }
    }
    return nil
}


func IsNotWin32Atom(IntPtr ptr) bool {
    return 0 != uint64(ptr)&HIWORDMASK
}
```

i also need

```
Marshal.StructureToPtr
@see https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/marshal.cs,48a38ffe8a227f92
Marshal.PtrToStructure
@see https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/marshal.cs,931fc84766e0e8cb
```

Updated information.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.allochglobal?view=net-5.0) for `Marshall.AllocHGlobal` says that it exposes Win32 [`LoadAlloc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.allochglobal?view=net-5.0), so perhaps there's a correpsonding Go method.

Comment: Can you also show us some code that highlights how do you want to use the WINMSG struct afterwards ?

Comment: updated the question; i understand calling methods via syscall, also used packages for this. but i need to prepare memory (which has to match exactly - bitwise) and pass it to those methods (via IntPtr or even Delegates) and this is what i never did before...

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to call a Win32 api function, you don't need to .NET specific wrapper for memory management.

There is a pattern to call windows dll functions.

You can see example in windows specific code from the standard library, or at some libs that interact with windows API :
in https://github.com/gofrs/flock, for example, they grouped that code in the [`flock_winapi.go` file](https://github.com/gofrs/flock/blob/75ec202958fd1654ff47064ba3ebffe14443f391/flock_winapi.go)

This post makes a decent job at explaining how to write code to call a specific function :

- [Breaking all the rules: Using Go to call Windows API](https://medium.com/@justen.walker/breaking-all-the-rules-using-go-to-call-windows-api-2cbfd8c79724)